# Python Error not letting program run because it says that the local variable is not defined

Tags: python

Well, it says that submission is not defined in this piece of code when it actually is. I am trying to use tkinter, hence the `.get()`
 and `reddit praw api`. I am trying to use the function saver_vars which saves the individual variables from the GUI and use them in order to make a request and then take that request in give it to request_1 which does something with it, it has more code. Do not worry about the formatting though because I know that it is formatted properly.

```
def saver_vars():

    global urlLink
    urlLink = e1.get()

    global submission_numb
    submission_numb = e2.get()

    global name_file
    name_file = e3.get()

    global File_Path
    File_Path = e4.get()
    File_Path.replace(r'\\', "/")

    global MidPicDir
    MidPicDir = e4.get()
    MidPicDir.replace(r'\\', "/")

    global choice
    choice = e5.get()
    nonurl=urlparse(urlLink)
    reddit_request1 = praw.Reddit(client_id='something',
                     client_secret="something", password='something!',
                     user_agent='something by /u/the_anti-vac', username='something')
    # try: 

    if choice == "1":
        submissions = reddit_request1.subreddit('AskReddit').hot(limit = int("{0}".format(submission_numb)))

    if choice == "2":
        submissions = reddit_request1.get_submission(submission_id=nonurl.path.split('/')[4])




    master.quit()

    request_1(submissions)



def request_1(submissions):
    submission_info = ""
    count_1 = 0
    for submission_1 in submissions:
        print("submissiontitle" + submission_1.title)
```

I want it to run without this error message `local variable 'submissions' referenced before assignment`. it puts this error at the `request_1`.

Comment: does it need to be `elif` rather than `if` for the second `if`?

Comment: presumably your `choice` variable is neither `"1"` or `"2"`, in which case `submissions` never gets defined. I can't understand where `choice` comes from and what it's supposed to be - but you probably want to add some sort of default case, and use an `if/elif/else` block to define it.

Comment: What will be the value of the `submissions` if choice value is "3" or "q"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that if your choice is not equal to either 1 or 2, there is no variable `submissions` created. Thus, you can make sure it will always exist by declaring it anywhere in the code before you use it or initialize it like in my example. You can use *None* keyword which will initialize the variable but keep it empty and ready for whatever you want to put there. It will look like that:

```
submissions = None

if choice == "1":
    submissions = reddit_request1.subreddit('AskReddit').hot(limit = int("{0}".format(submission_numb)))

if choice == "2":
    submissions = reddit_request1.get_submission(submission_id=nonurl.path.split('/')[4])
...
```

Or you can make the if..else if.. else for better code practice:

```
if choice == "1":
    submissions = reddit_request1.subreddit('AskReddit').hot(limit = int("{0}".format(submission_numb)))
elif choice == "2":
    submissions = reddit_request1.get_submission(submission_id=nonurl.path.split('/')[4])
else:
    submissions = None
... 
...
```

It should work this way.

Comment: You seem to be assuming Python has block scope, but it doesn't - it has function scope. The problem is simply that submissions does not get defined at all (and therefore isn't in scope anywhere) when `choice` is not equal to either `"1"` or `"2"` [Your solution will actually work, provided `None` is an acceptable value to use - but your explanation of why this is needed is misleading imo.]

Comment: @RobinZigmond, you are right. I corrected my explanation. There is function scope in Python.